# Is there a way to check in Java runtime if an object has a specific method?

Tags: java, rtti

I have a class and it has multiple subclasses which each implement their own methods. Some of these subclasses have common method which I need to call. Is there a way in java to know if the object has a method (without using `instanceof`)?

Comment: Take a look at the Reflection API. A better solution might be to define a series of interfaces as its easier and quicker to check for membership in a interface then to reflect a class

Comment: Instead of using reflection you should either have them all implement an interface that declares the method, or put the method in the superclass.

Comment: even the ones you can't call (without reflection): http://ideone.com/vy2OP0

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it's a bad idea.  Please don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This probably points to a design flaw, but you could always use reflection to check if a method exists:

```
public static boolean hasMethod(Object obj, String methodName) {
    return Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getMethods())
                 .anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equals(methodName));
}
```

This, of course, could be refined to include the method's signature too, but the basic idea remains the same.